# Markdown to HTML while using c++ for designing backend compiler

Tags: html, compiler-construction, markdown, abstract-syntax-tree, flex-lexer

How can I convert the .md(markdown) files to HTML page view using c++ as base language!?
Using own compiler with softwares such as Flex and Bison...pls let me know the steps to be followed

I've started using using Flex and bison, but yet to understand the complete workflow.

Comment: There's two questions here, please pick one. Also, check [maddy](https://github.com/progsource/maddy).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Step 1: write parser that understands markdown and reads it into some data structure that is convenient for you. Step 2: write an algorithm that saves the data from your data structure as HTML.